# Regular expression for a string starting with some string

Tags: java, regex

I have some string, that has this type: `(notice)Any_other_string` (notes that : `()` has in this string`.

So, I want to separate this string to 2 part : `(notice)` and the rest. I do as follow :

```
private static final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("(^\\(notice\\))([a-z_A-Z1-9])+");
String content = "(notice)Stack Over_Flow 123";

        Matcher m = p1.matcher(content);

        System.out.println("Printing");

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(0));
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

I hope the result will be `(notice)` and `Stack Over_Flow 123`, but instead, the result is : `(notice)Stack` and `(notice)`

I cannot explain this result. Which regex is suitable for my purpose?

Comment: you're not matching the space character

Comment: @user2264587 yes. I have add a space. but, group 3 just `3`. not `Stack Over_Flow 123`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue 1: `group(0)` will always return the **entire** match - this is specified in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) - and the actual capturing groups start from index 1. Simply replace it with the following:

```
System.out.println(m.group(1));
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Issue 2: You do not take spaces and other characters, such as underscores, into account (not even the digit 0). I suggest using the dot, `.`, for matching unknown characters. Or include `\\s` (whitespace) and `_` into your regex. Either of the following regexes should work:

```
(^\\(notice\\))(.+)
(^\\(notice\\))([A-Za-z0-9_\\s]+)
```

Note that you need the + inside the capturing group, or it will only find the last character of the second part.

Comment: @AntP Should've noticed that.. *Goes to bed*